# Getting the error," No matching member function for call to 'write' " in metal compute shader

Tags: swift, kernel, metal, compute-shader

[image]

I'm sure this is a very basic error but I have just tried to create my first compute shader in metal Xcode and I'm receiving this error. I have no idea what the cause of this error is and how to fix it. I can't find any documentation on the internet of this error and have come here desperate for help.

This is the code I have used to try and setup the compute encoder:

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code, not a picture.

Answer (score 1):

These are the signatures for `write` methods on `texture2d`

```
void write(Tv color, uint2 coord, uint lod = 0)
void write(Tv color, ushort2 coord,
ushort lod = 0)
```

Refer to [Metal Shading Language specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), section 6.12.3 for more info.

`write` takes two arguments: the color you are going to write and the position where to write.

`output.write(position` doesn't make any sense since it's not clear what you are trying to write.